# h1 tags inside a paragraph effect seo?

Tags: html, seo

Ok so I'm not sure if this will effect my page seo? What I've done is created a paragraph and put my h1 tags in the middle of it. I'm trying to rank for freelance web design belfast and it's in the middle of the text and because it looks better design wise on the page. On all other pages its the title by it's self except the home page, I'm just interested if this will effect page rank for sacrifice of design.

```
                <span class="meet">Meet Jonny.</span><br/>
    <span class="freelance">An award-winning <h1 class="h1-home">freelance web designer based in Belfast, Northern Ireland</h1>, who creates eye-catching responsive websites. Follow him on <a target="_blank" href="">Twitter</a>, flick through his <a target="_blank" href="">Flickr</a>, or just say <a target="_blank" href="">hello.</a></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The h1 tags will be recognised as more important keyswords for your page. What will matter more is that the actual content of the website is extensive enough and that it includes a lot of relevant text, about/synonyms of the keywords. Incoming web links will also increase it's importance. I don't think the h1 tags will do THAT much, but they will help google determine the important words on your side.

Comment: So coding the h1 inside text won't have a negative effect on SEO?

Comment: I don't necessarily think it will have a negative effect. However, it's not meant to be used like that. You could use a class css attribute instead for that.

Answer (score 1):

It makes little or no difference to your sites rankings. If I were you, I would worry more about the design, speed and experience. What you did there may seem inappropriate, but if the page has enough valuable content, on pages and its sub pages and people are hanging around these webpages, **they should do just fine in search.**

Found this thread. You may find it useful.
http://moz.com/community/q/h1-tag-mandatory

Answer (score 0):

Most of the websites design H1 to indicate what is the content of the page about. They are **heading tags** generally used to present organized/structured content. IMHO, it looks like you are using H1 for styling and not really as heading of structured content. You can use general css styling for that and they will have pretty much the same effect as stuffing it inside the H1 tag. Theoretically it will not affect SEO ranking, but in my opinion try using a CSS styling for that and use H1 for heading tags. Also make sure you have a (one and only) H1 tag on the page.

http://www.searchenginejournal.com/2014-important-h1-tag-seo/106613/